# Why is param moveY not apearing? Pygame update method

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to play around with pygame and I can draw an image as a sprite on the screen. I'm trying to move the sprite around with WASD by changing the x and y variables.

When I run the program, the sprite draws but doesn't move when I press the correct keys.

EDIT: I added an update method and the moveY param is saying it is not there, even though it clearly is, why is this?

Here's the code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = demon
        self.pos = [x,y]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(self)
        moveXY = [moveX,moveY]
        
        Sprite.pos[x] += moveXY[moveX]
        Sprite.pos[y] += moveXY[moveY] 
        
        

        
        
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

demon = pygame.image.load("C:/programming/doomman/cacodemon.png").convert_alpha()

x = 300
y = 300

my_sprite = Sprite((x, y))
all_sprites_list.add(my_sprite)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Demon Dance")
carryOn = True
        
while carryOn == True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                carryOn=False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    Sprite.update(0, 50)
                if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    Sprite.update(0, -50)
                if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    Sprite.update(50, 0)
                if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    Sprite.update(-50, 0)
                    
    
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the pygame API, but integers in Python are passed by value (sort of), meaning that here: `my_sprite = Sprite((x, y))` x and y are copied to the function. That means that when you change the value of x or y it doesnt get reflected in my_sprite. Is there a method for modifying the sprite object directly?

Comment: Looks like you can define an `update` method for the sprite. I would recommend looking into that and modifying your x and y coords by calling said method: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite

Comment: I've added an update method, still isn't working, will update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect` for the position.

Therefore you need to update the `rect` attribute after changing the position (`pos`) of the *Sprite*:

```py
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = demon
        self.pos = [pos[0], pos[1]]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        Sprite.pos[x] += moveX
        Sprite.pos[y] += moveY 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
```

---

You don't actually need the `pos` attribute at all. You can move the *Sprite* by changing the position stored in `rect`:

```py
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = demon
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        self.rect.x += moveX
        self.rect.y += moveY
```

---

Additionally `update` is an instance method. You need to call it with the object instead of the class:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    my_sprite.update(0, 50)
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    my_sprite.update(0, -50)
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    my_sprite.update(50, 0)
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    my_sprite.update(-50, 0)
```

Comment: How I'm getting a TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'moveY'

Comment: @TheBearSlicer Thank you. You're welcome.